# DHCP request for multiple IPs at once

Tags: dhcp

In DHCP, a DHCP client and a DHCP server go through the protocol exchange (DISCOVER, OFFER, REQUEST, ACK) so that the client ends up with an IP address allocated to it that is also tracked in the server.

Is it possible to arrange something so that a client can obtain *multiple* IP address allocations? For example, a client making multiple requests, or a client indicating how many IPs are required, etc. Any (wild) idea is welcome.

Comment: Unfortunately, questions about hosts/servers and protocols above OSI layer-4 are off-topic here.

Comment: Oops, I was not aware of that. Thank you for pointing it out. Any recommendation on which stack exchange site is appropriate for DHCP questions and answers?

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible to arrange something so that a client can obtain multiple IP address allocations?

Theoretically, yes. That client would need to initiate multiple DORA cycles and pass different values in the *client identifier* option 61 each time. That field is used in conjunction with *chaddr* to uniquely identify a client endpoint.

Of course, the server would also need to honor option 61.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2131#section-2

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2132#section-9.14

*Usually though*, multiple IP addresses only make sense in different VLANs and subnets, so the client would initiate an independent DORA for each VLAN with no extra options required.

Comment: Thank you, @Zac67!